# How to cut off the trailing comma when using an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that uses check boxes to create and an array and then output the array with comma separated values. I can't figure out how to get the last comma not to echo. I am very new at PHP looking for a little help.

```
    <?php $checked = $_POST['features'];
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
    echo $checked[$i] . ", ";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHPs built-in [`implode()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) function:

```
echo implode(', ', $checked);
```

But be aware of XSS attacks if you print out user input the exact same way as it was inserted by the user. So I can write to `$_POST['features][0]` something like `<script>alert('hello world');</script>` and this will be executed by the browser when you implode the array and print it out. So use [`array_map()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php) to sanitize the user input:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $checked));
```

And as the user can insert anything through this POST data you should check that it is actually an array:

```
if(is_array($checked) === true)
    echo implode(', ', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $checked));
else
    echo 'No valid data provided';
```

Answer (score 0):

Save to a variable use rtrim  (',', $variable) then echo variable out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to echo out your array without having to loop through the array:

```
echo print_r($array, true);
```

This will display a human-readable representation of your array without the trailing comma, although it won't display null, true and false like using `var_export()` does.

Added bonus:
If you add the html `<pre>` tag around your code like this:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, true) . '</pre>';
```

You'll get an even nicer look at your array that preserves spaces and line breaks.